# Laravel TestCase->postJson to external url?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing

I'm trying to write a Laravel test case where I need to make an HTTP Post Request to an external API.  But my `$this->postJson()` keeps giving me an exception.  Here's an excerpt from my code:

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;

class PurchaseTest extends TestCase
{

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testPurchasePolicy()
    {
        $response = $this->postJson('https://apitest.cybersource.com/flex/v1/',['cardNumber'=>'4111111111111111']);
        print_r($response->json());
        $response->assertOk();
    }
}
```

This gives the result:

```
Array
(
    [message] =>
    [exception] => Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
    [file] => /var/www/projects/local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php
    [line] => 43
    [trace] => Array
 (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /var/www/projects/local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php
                    [line] => 162
                    [function] => handleMatchedRoute
                    [class] => Illuminate\Routing\AbstractRouteCollection
             ///  --> then a stack trace of laravel code that failed
)
```

You won't be able to fully run my code because it requires some API keys with cybersource.  But i'm pretty sure my code is failing because I'm not properly telling Laravel that the API i want to access is an external resource.

What is the idiomatic way for Laravel to connect with an external URL?

Comment: which laravel version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an HTTP Client.

1. Install guzzle with composer:

`composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`

Then:

For laravel 7.x and above, use the HTTP Client facade:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$response = Http::get('http://test.com');
```

Check the laravel documentation about [HTTP Client usage](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-client).

For laravel 6.x or below, use guzzle like:

```php
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/user', [
    'auth' => ['user', 'pass']
]);
```

check the [Guzzle docs.](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/)

Comment: The question is clearly about making a POST request to an API, not sure why this was marked accepted as it doesn't explain what's wrong with using `postJson()` nor does it provide a viable replacement.

Comment: @miken32  This question is about connecting to an external api from the laravel testing cases, `postJson` is not made for testing external apis, this person was trying to connect to an external api, that's why using the Http facade or client is the solution and viable replacement.

Comment: I understand what `postJson()` is for, but the explanation of why it didn't work should be in the answer. And using `Http` class is the correct solution, but your answer should show how to use it to make the POST request in the question. Instead it only shows a simple GET request.

Answer (score -1):

In new Laravel

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$response = Http::get('http://theusoffice.com/');
```

and if you need to use `https` and having issues with it try

```
$response = Http::withOptions(['verify' => false])->get('https://www.google.com/');
```

Comment: If you need to get hit with a man-in-the-middle attack, by all means give that code a try.